# how to set limit for key-value paired ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
//i have a json object as 
var jsonObject= {
        "sekhar88Question": [{
            "ID": "3330",
            "post_content": "Anssssssssss"
        }, {
            "ID": "3331",
            "post_content": "Answwwwwwwwwwww"
        }],
        "qqqqyyyyyyyyyy": null,
        "harishQuestion": null,
        "harishQuestion2": null
    }
}
```

// displaying the values using ng-repeat

```
  <div ng-repeat="(key, data) in jsonObject">
     Q. {{key}}
    <div ng-repeat="answers in data">
       A. {{answers.post_content}}
     </div>
   </div>
```

// the json object has 4 key value pair . I Want to show only 2 key value pair data in view. ie.. limit the json data.

Comment: did you try limitTo: filter?
ng-repeat="answers in data | limitTo:2"

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ref_limitto

Comment: jsonObject is not in array format  limitTo  is not working

Comment: how about ng-if="$index < 2" check?
https://plnkr.co/edit/K9HP3AWrvw6inW33UkGd?p=preview